# How to delete a item of a bidimensional char array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've working with a bidimensional char array pointer, in other words, an array of strings arrays. This pointer is inside an `struct` and I'm trying to delete a string array.

In other words, if I have the following array:

```
{ { "Foo", "Bar" }, { "Baz", "Fee" }, { "Var", "Bar" } }
```

And I'm trying to delete the middle array

```
{ { "Foo", "Bar" }, { "Var", "Bar" } }
```

The `struct` is the following

```
struct Data {
    int size;

    char(*items)[10][64];
}
```

I tried to iterate the array and move the front positions one back, as follows (suppose I'm trying to eliminate the position 1)

```
int positionInArray = 1;
// Suppose that data struct is filled
for (int x = positionInArray; x < data->size; x+ ) {
  (*(*data->items[x])) = (*(*data->items[x+1]));
}
```

I'm not sure it's the right way and obviously I'm not able to delete the item.

Comment: *`char(*items)[10][64];`* – Now that's odd. How do you ... um ... but data into that "array"?

Comment: Reallocating memory then `scanf("%s", set->items[set->size - 1][x]);` I mean, actually the array is initialized as `char(*items)[0][64]`

Comment: *Reallocating memory* – how so? please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *the array is initialized as char(*items)[0][64]* – you realize that `items` is not an array, right?

Comment: @Swordfish That's a flexible array member.

Comment: I do not know why it is so important to add the information, that part is already done and correctly, I can save information without problem, but here is the:[example](https://gist.github.com/Alessnsg/d75bfc776f7f198b1b4191f8f8022e46)

Comment: There is no concept "delete from array" in C. Arrays are fixed length, and every element contains something.

Comment: @Barmar Thats nothing flexible, it's a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Swordfish It's not a pointer to an array, it's an array of pointers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: @Barmar I love you too, but `char(*items)[10][64];` is still a ptr to an array of `char`.

Comment: @Swordfish You're right. It should be `char *items[10][64]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's less confusing if you use ordinary array indexing, rather than pointer dereferencing. You can use `memcpy()` to copy a whole row at once.

If the strings are dynamically allocated, then before you shift the array elements, you need to free the items pointed to by the row you're deleting.

```
for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(data->items[0])/sizeof(data->items[0][0]); x++) {
    free(data->items[positionInArray][x]);
}
```

Then the limit of your `for` loop to shift the rows should be `size-1`, otherwise you'll try to copy the row past the last valid one.

```
for (int x = positionInArray; x < data->size-1; x++) {
    memcpy(data->items[x], data->items[x+1], sizeof(data->items[x]));
}

data->size--;
```

Comment: Thanks it solve my problem, I'm still getting a error on `free` call, but I can check it by myself. Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? I assumed that the elements of the array are all dynamically-allocated strings.

Comment: You said in a comment that you reallocate memory before the scanf.

Comment: Yes, all are dinamycally-allocated, `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` I'm assuming that I'm not passing the correct memory address.

Comment: If you can't solve it, post a new question that shows how you're allocating the strings and then doing this deletion.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thank you so much.